# Is MEMORY_AND_DISK always better that DISK_ONLY when persisting an RDD to disk?

Tags: apache-spark

Using Apache Spark why would I choose to persist an RDD using storage level DISK_ONLY rather than using MEMORY_AND_DISK or MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER ?

Is there any use-case where using DISK_ONLY would give better performance than MEMORY_AND_DISK or MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER.

Answer (score 4):

Simple example - you may have one relatively great RDD rdd1 and one smalled RDD rdd2. You want to store both of them.

If you apply persist MEMORY_AND_DISK on both, then both of them will be spilled to disk resulting in slower reaed.

But you may take a different approach - you may store rdd1 with DISK_ONLY. It may just so happen that thanks to this move you can store rdd2 right in the memory with cache() option and you will be able to read it faster.

Comment: also you could save money when running it on a cluster - larger memory clusters are more expensive to run.

Comment: Yup, but I guess in that case (lower memory cluster) MEMORY_AND_DISK would also work fine.